# Setting pagination for images attached to a post

Tags: posts, pagination, get-posts

I am trying to figure out how to paginate a post for it's images. I have a custom post type set up to act like a gallery - images only. And would like to paginate the images. I am having a hard time trying to figure out where to start with this.

I am using get_posts() within the loop to get the images attached to the post. I would like to set it up so 30 images display per page.

Any idea where I should start? Or do I need to alter the way I have this gallery feature set up in WP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination/

Comment: Answered here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154945/9884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`paginate_links()`](http://queryposts.com/function/paginate_links/) to paginate the total gallery. This highly depends on your permalink settings. The best would be to check [other answers on that topic here on WPSE](https://www.google.at/search?q=wordpress.stackexchange.com%3A+paginate_links&oq=wordpress.stackexchange.com%3A+paginate_links&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

## Next/Prev post links for attachments.

Than there's also the task to navigate on single attachment display.

### Default API function/template tag

There's the [`adjacent_post_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/adjacent_post_link/) function that can link to the next or previous post - an attachment is a post of the type "attachment". It echos the output filtered by

```
apply_filters( "{$adjacent}_post_link", $format, $link );
```

where `$adjacent` is `previous` or `next`.

#### Example

```
adjacent_post_link( 
     '%link'        // format
    ,'%date/%title' // link
    ,false          // in_same_cat
    ,''             // excluded_categories
    ,false          // next/previous (previous = true)
);
```

### Inner Details

If the post title of the attachment is empty, it gets replaced by a "Previous/Next Post" text. This title then has all `the_title` filter callback functions attached. You'd need to remove them if you don't want this:

```
function wpse66660_attachment_remove_title_cbs( $title, $id )
{
    is_attachment() AND remove_all_filters( current_filter() );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse66660_attachment_remove_title_cbs', 100, 2 );
```

#### Tags

As you've seen above ↑, there're three "tags", that you can use: `%link`, `%date` and `%title`.

The output of the function would be something like the following:

```
'<a href="'.get_permalink($post).'" rel="prev/next">' . $link . '</a>'
```

Now `%title` gets replaced by the post title and `%date` replaced by the post date. This allows you to add any custom value to the HTML-anchor tag.

The `%link` allows you to replace everything that is in the final string (HTML-anchor + link + rel + value) with something custom that aligns with your permalink settings.

Comment: Thanks for this! I should have mentioned that I am also using the prettyPhoto jQuery gallery plugin. The galleries could have a load of images in them as well. So the question is how to do I paginate but still keep them all in the gallery that pops up. Or should I be using some kind of lazy loader for images? Not sure how the code you presented would fit into using the prettyPhoto gallery plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with a) the plugin name and b) a link to the plugin.